# WPF MediaElement Stop reset to beginning (first frame)

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I am working on a task to manually handle video playback in WPF. I am using `MediaElement` for that. I want the video to reset to the beginning (first frame) when I stop the playback by calling MediaElement's `Stop` method.

When I call Stop method, it does stop at the current frame and it looks like it is paused. Though when I call `Play` method, the video starts from the beginning. But I want the UI to show the first frame of the video when I call Stop method. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If there is no workaround - make a cool start screen and overlay it - this is just a comment.

Comment: Maybe set position to 0 manually and then call Stop?

Comment: @Evk I already tried that, didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter will try that as the last escape